# Django URL deserializing issue

Tags: regex, django, url

I have the following route in my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)/$', render_search, name="search_by_tag"),
```

So, I pass a tag there and get a result, e.g `/tag/python/`, `/tag/django/`

But it fails when I pass there something like `/tag/C++/`, and it even fails when I pass encoded value: `/tag/C%2B%2B/`

How can I fix that and accept the encoded values on back-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about regex here. Regex pattern that you-ve provided will accept only letters, digits, underscore and '-'. To accept all possible characters (excluding '/' and '?') you should make regex like this:

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[^/?]+)/$', render_search, name="search_by_tag"),
```

but it's not good idea, you should better slugify your tag names and use that slugified form in url instead.

Comment: First of all - they will look ugly. Some characters will be encoded by browsers, some of them you will encode on your site and it won't look nice. Secondly - there may be some issues in some browsers, and third reason - when someone will copy that url and paste it somewhere - that input may disallow some characters in URL. It's just good convention to put inside url only some characters.